# is it secure to use this.props.match.params.id

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am newbie in react and redux,  i am trying to create new post using `this.props.match.params.id`

```
componentDidMount()
 {
   this.props.dispatch(userActions.getAll(this.props.match.params.id));
 }

....................

<button type="button" 
 onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "ADD_NEW_POST", 
 id: this.props.match.params.id })} >Save
</button>
```

My question is , how much secure i use `this.props.match.params.id` for CRUD application ?

---

**EDIT**

My Link is `` <Link to={`/addpost/${item.id}`}>Rooms</Link> ``, then we use `getAll(this.props.match.params.id)` and submit using above code

In **nodejs**,

```
router.post('/addpost/:id', (req, res, next) =>{
    Users.findById(req.params.id, function (err, data) {
    ..............
    ..............
```

Comment: What do you mean by *secure*?

Comment: What do you mean 'secure'? Also the answer is almost certainly some variant of "no, but it doesn't really matter".

Comment: i mean, user can change :id using browser link etc...

Comment: Are you connected to a database? If you are, why not have the database generate your next post Id

Comment: It's Javascript. Of course they can. They can change almost anything. Agree with @Neil, why are you *generating* ids client-side?

Comment: ok i will, explain in my question. wait

Comment: updated with more code ! thanks :)

Comment: @JaredSmith i am not generating any id in client side

Comment: This is still no where near enough information. If your question is merely 'is it okay to authorize based on an id received from the client and sent via post' then the answer is *yes*, with some caveats. If you are asking if a user can modify data that they're sending to you directly, then the answer is also yes, they can monkey with almost anything via the browser's console.

Comment: i have jwt checking each and every request, is it enough or any other validation need ? thanks for your reply :)